# changing background colour with expression for time value SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have an issue with changing colour of a column through an expression. The column of which I want tot change the background colour of has a time value. The format is hh:mm, currently I am using this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!FacturatieTijd.Value  >= 5, "Red", "Lime")
```

With this expression it only changes the colour of the cells which dont have a value in it(*Null)*. I have tried using "05:00" in my expression but that gives an error..

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're going to want to get the hours separated from your time to compare correctly.  To do that, you'll need to use the `Datepart` function within your `IIF`.  Try the following expression.

```
=IIF(DatePart("h", Fields!FacturatieTijd.Value)  >= 5, "Red", "Lime")
```

In theory, this should extract an integer value for the hour and compare it against 5, giving you the result you need.  I haven't actually tested this, but it should work.